# C++: what is Mat3f?

Tags: c++, matrix

I try to solve a task for my studies. We got a little framework in which we are asked to put our solution to. There is a line that I don't understand:

```
Mat3f R (conf.R);
```

Part of the task is to multiply matrices. So I guess Mat3f stands for a float matrix. But what stands the number 3 for? And what is the `conf.R` argument for? What will be the dimensions of the resulting matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not standard - it is part of some library the code is using. The only person who could possibly know what that library is is you. Of course, we could probably find out with a [quick Google](http://www.arts.rpi.edu/public_html/lynchm2/comm4940/FEARDoxygen/_mat3f_8cpp-source.html), but you should do that, not us.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I thought Mat3f would be part of the standard library and with this assumption I did't find any satisfying results. I can't say if the link you provided is 100% adequate, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact meaning of the 3 in `Mat3f` is library-specific, but a normal games programmer seeing it for the first time would expect `Mat3f` to be a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Thank you! Can you guess what the parameter *could* be for?

Comment: `R` probably stands for rotation, which can be a 3x3 matrix, and `Conf.R` is perhaps the *configuration* i.e. start rotation?  That being a good guess, the code would take the configured start rotation and copy it to a matrix called `R`, which it then likely applies further rotation to in the code that follows.